# Is it a bug to validate dynamic TinyMCE with bootstrap validator or something wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

All

I'm using Bootstrap Validator now. But I have a problem to validate dynamic TinyMCE.

If only 1 TinyMCE, it works.

But if I have more than 1 TinyMCE all of my TinyMCE will get same error although it's only 1 of my TinyMCE doesnt meet the requirement, all of my TinyMCE that already meet the requirement will get same error too.
But if I'm not using TinyMCE on my textarea, it works. I think there's a problem with multiple TinyMCE with same name.

I dont know what's wrong. Already see the example to validate multiple name and tinymce from Bootstrap Validator, but cant solve this problem.

My code exactly same with the example, the different only I added TinyMCE on my textarea.
http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/adding-dynamic-field/
http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/tinymce/

This is my code

```
<div class="panel-body hide" id="formUser">
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label'>Name</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter Name' name='Name[]' >
   </div>

   <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label'>Hobbies</label>
      <textarea class='form-control' name='Hobbies[]'  ></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the code to add dynamic TinyMCE and validate it

```
    function initTinyMCE(){
        tinymce.init({
            forced_root_block : "", 
            force_br_newlines : true,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            selector: "textarea#desc"+i,
            theme: "modern",
            width: 1287,
            height: 400,
            relative_urls : false,
            remove_script_host: false,
            plugins: [
                 "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                 "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                 "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor jbimages"
           ],
           toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | fontselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
           style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
            ],
            setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the hobbies field
                $('.formUser').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'Hobbies[]');
            });
        }


         });    
    }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    //initTinyMCE();
        .bootstrapValidator({
        excluded: [':disabled'],
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            'Name[]': {
                message: 'The nameis not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The nameis required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The title must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/,
                        message: 'The name can only consist of alphabetical, number and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            'Hobbies[]': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'The hobbies must be between 5 and 200 characters long',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the plain text without HTML


                            var text = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({
                                format: 'text'
                            });
                            return text.length <= 200 && text.length >= 5;
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    })


    .on('click','.addUser', function() {
        var $template = $('#formUser'),
            $clone    = $template
                            .clone()
                            .removeClass('hide')
                            .removeAttr('id')
                            .insertBefore($template),

        $option1   = $clone.find('[name="Name[]"]');
        $option2   = $clone.find('[name="Hobbies[]"]');
        $clone.find(".wrap").attr("id","wrap"+i);
        $clone.find("textarea").attr("id","desc"+i);
        $clone.find("textarea").attr("class","form-control desc"+i);
        $clone.find('.wrapper').attr('id','wrapper'+i);
        $clone.find('button').attr('onclick','deleteForm(\'wrapper'+i+'\')');
        initTinyMCE();

        // Add new field
        $('.formUser').bootstrapValidator('addField',$option1);
        $('.formUser').bootstrapValidator('addField',$option2);

        i++;
    })

 });
```

Waiting for your help guys.
Really appreciate for your help guys.

Thank You

Comment: hi all, could you please help me to solve this problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html

```
<form id="tinyMCEForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Hobbies</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="hobbies" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" name="myBtn" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
                console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + editor.getContent({
                    format: 'text'
                }));
                $('#tinyMCEForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'hobbies');
            });
        }
    });
    $('#tinyMCEForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
        excluded: [':disabled'],
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            hobbies: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'The hobbies must be between 5 and 200 characters long',
                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the plain text without HTML
                            var text = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({
                                format: 'text'
                            });

                            return text.length <= 200 && text.length >= 5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
        .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```